# Exception Value: 'NoneType' object is unsubscriptable

Tags: django, django-models

Hi I've recently created a new app for the managing my contact forms. I have a model called 'Brochure' and a model which holds all the information that gets filled in from the contact form on the website. However when i try and add a 'Brochure' entry I get the error displayed above. Here is my code and no idea why the error is appearing.

models.py

```
from django.db import models



class ContactForm(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length="300")

    company = models.CharField(max_length="200")

    email = models.CharField(max_length="300")

    subject = models.TextField()

    message = models.TextField()

    address = models.TextField()

    brochure = models.ManyToManyField("Brochure", null=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        self.name

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Contact Enquiry"
        verbose_name_plural = "Contact Enquiries"

class Brochure(models.Model):



    title = models.CharField(max_length="200")


    def __unicode__(self):
        self.title


    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Brochure"
        verbose_name_plural = "Brochures"
```

views.py

```
from contact_enquiries import forms
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect


    def contact(request):
        if request.method == 'POST':
            form = forms.ContactEnquiryForm(request.POST)
                    en_form = forms.BrochureRequestForm(request.POST)

                    print(request.POST)
            if form.is_valid():
                #print "Form looks good!"
                #e = models.ContactEnquiry(form.cleaned_data)
                #e.save()
                form.save()
                return HttpResponseRedirect('/thanks/')
        else:
            form = forms.ContactEnquiryForm()
                    en_form = forms.BrochureRequestForm()

        return render(request, 'contact.html', {
                'contact_form' : form,
                            'enquiry_form' : en_form,

                })
```

forms.py
    from django.forms import ModelForm
    from django import forms

```
from contact_enquiries import models

class ContactEnquiryForm(ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = models.ContactForm

        fields=('name','email','company', 'subject', 'message')




class BrochureRequestForm(ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = models.ContactForm

        fields = ('name', 'email', 'company', 'address', 'brochure',)

        widgets = {'brochure': forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple()}
```

Any help would be much appreciated

STACK TRACE

```
Traceback:
File "/var/www/website.co.uk/website/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  115.                         response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/var/www/website.co.uk/website/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py" in wrapper
  372.                 return self.admin_site.admin_view(view)(*args, **kwargs)
File "/var/www/website.co.uk/website/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  91.                     response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/var/www/website.co.uk/website/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/views/decorators/cache.py" in _wrapped_view_func
  89.         response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/var/www/website.co.uk/website/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/sites.py" in inner
  202.             return view(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/var/www/website.co.uk/website/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in _wrapper
  25.             return bound_func(*args, **kwargs)
File "/var/www/website.co.uk/website/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  91.                     response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/var/www/website.co.uk/website/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in bound_func
  21.                 return func(self, *args2, **kwargs2)
File "/var/www/website.co.uk/website/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/db/transaction.py" in inner
  223.                 return func(*args, **kwargs)
File "/var/www/website.co.uk/website/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py" in add_view
  1009.                 self.log_addition(request, new_object)
File "/var/www/website.co.uk/website/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py" in log_addition
  530.             action_flag     = ADDITION
File "/var/www/website.co.uk/website/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/models.py" in log_action
  18.         e = self.model(None, None, user_id, content_type_id, smart_text(object_id), object_repr[:200], action_flag, change_message)

Exception Type: TypeError at /admin/contact_enquiries/brochure/add/
Exception Value: 'NoneType' object is unsubscriptable
```

Comment: can you show the stack trace ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `__unicode__` method of models `ContactForm` needs to `return` something

You could change

```
def __unicode__(self):
    self.name
```

To

```
def __unicode__(self):
    return "%s" % self.name
```

The same thing with class `Brochure`

Comment: Thank you so much! Been going round in circles for ages, will accept as soon as I can. Thanks again!

Comment: Glad to have been of help.

Comment: A function or method should always return something explicitly. Else python would return None for you. @Mark